# Actividades en android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Tengo dudas acerca del ciclo de vida de una actividad. no me queda muy claro que se debe hacer en que método. Se supone que en `onCreate` simplemente debo declarar las vista y los elementos que contiene  y en `onStart` y `onResumen` debo de poner el funcionamiento de lo que he declarado?

Por ejemplo declaro un botón en `onCreate`, luego en `onStart` o en `onResumen` debo de declarar lo que ese botón va a hacer?

Answer (score 6):

> onCreate()

debes declarar en inicializar todos tus variables, también debes inicializar los `listener` para los botones y en general todas las demás componentes.

> onStart()

es el método que se llama cuando la actividad empieza a ser visible para el usuario

> onResume()

es el método que se llama después de `onStart()` pero también es el método llamado cuando una actividad vuelve a estar accesible para el usuario, pero todavía no es visible para él (piensa que todo esto pasa en mili-segundos), después de que haya sido ocultada por el sistema (por ejemplo el usuario recibe una llamada o deja el teléfono en la mesa y pasa a modo reposo). Aquí depende de la aplicación en sí, por ejemplo puedes volver a llamar a una API-REST para volver a cargar los datos.

> onPause()

es el método que llama el SO cuando una actividad se va a background, es decir empieza a estar fuera de la vista del usuario (ejemplo el teléfono pasa a modo reposo), aquí puedes guardar datos, por ejemplo, si estas en una app que tiene un mapa puedes guardar el zoom que usaba el usuario, la latitud y la longitud.

En general todo depende de la aplicación en sí, pero te debes plantear que hacer en tu aplicación cuando tu vista pasa a background y que hacer cuando vuelve de ese estado, para ello es para lo que disponemos de todos esos métodos, para resolver preguntas como:

¿Qué tengo que hacer cuando mi app pasa a modo reposo?
   ¿Qué tengo que hacer cuando mi app sale de modo reposo?
   ¿Qué tengo que hacer si alguien esta usando mi app y le llaman por
   teléfono?

Aquí tienes un ejemplo que espero te ayude a entenderlo

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private final static String TAG = "TestActivity";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Log.i(TAG, "On Create .....");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() { 
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i(TAG, "On Destroy .....");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() { 
        super.onPause();
        Log.i(TAG, "On Pause .....");
    }


    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        Log.i(TAG, "On Restart .....");
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.i(TAG, "On Resume .....");
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.i(TAG, "On Start .....");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.i(TAG, "On Stop .....");
    }
}
```

Y aquí tienes el el ciclo de vida de una actividad
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Son los estados de una aplicacion, son estados que tu no no puedes controlar de una manera directa, onCreate es una referencia a cuando se lanza alguna actividad, on start cuando inicia, on resume, cuando se detiene.

Comment: si, pero me refiero a que se debe de hacer en cada estado de la actividad, como ya sabemos en onCreate referenciamos los objetos, por ejemplo boton1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.boton_imagen); boton1.setOnClickListener(this); , entonces onStart y onResumen para que me sirven?